# Why I have memory leak in C/MEX?

Tags: c, memory, mex

I'm totally beginner in C/MEX. This is a simple code for call the "magic" function from MATLAB. I have no idea why I get "Out of memory" message.

```
#include <mex.h>
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    #define A_IN prhs[0]
    #define A_OUT plhs[0]
    mxArray *R;
    R=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(A_IN,A_IN,mxREAL);
    mexCallMATLAB(1, R, 1, &A_IN, "magic");
    A_OUT = mxDuplicateArray(R);
    mxDestroyArray(R);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is this code written by you?

Comment: Yes i wrote it to find the error.

Comment: Maybe show us the error too? or explain what your trying to do with this function?! for me it looks like as would the error be triggerd by parsing an wrong memory block in or by calling the functions with wrong values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I wrote this func. to practice and find the errors in longer functions. The error is "Out of memory" as i wrote in the question: "Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options." I use the MATLAB built-in compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A_OUT` seems to be a duplicate of `R`. Basically, according to the [doc](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/apiref/mxduplicatearray.html) (that you should read before asking any question, just sayin' :) ), is creating a new `array`. Calling this function will allocate more memory to store this copy.

So the leak is from `A_OUT`. You can use the **valgrind** tool to help you finding those, with the options `--leak-check=full`. Of course, compile with the debug flags of your compiler (`-g3` for **gcc**), it will give you most of the informations you need to fix your leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't seem to have a memory leak.
The problem seems to be in the size of the matrix you're passing to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` (documentation on `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublematrix.html)).

`A_IN` in your code is actually a MATLAB array (`const mxarray *`), not a integer, which is the type `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` needs (more correctly, it needs an `mwSize`). Your compiler is probably converting the array pointer to an integer, and using that as the size. You might try this code instead, which uses `mwGetScalar` to get the value in `A_IN`, and then converts it from a double to an integer `mwSize`:

```
...
mwSize matrixSize;
matrixSize = (mwSize) mxGetScalar(A_IN);
R = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(matrixSize, matrixSize, mxREAL);
...
```

But actually, you don't have to create `R` yourself; MATLAB will create it for you when you call `mexCallMATLAB`, according to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html).

Finally, you should be able to assign `R` directly to `A_OUT`, without making a copy of the array.

You shouldn't have any memory leaks though with your code as-is, because MATLAB [automatically deallocates](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/memory-management.html#f26107) any matrices you create when leaving the MEX function, unless you tell it otherwise.